# SQL ISSUE- Help in query count + min

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tables:

```
[dbo].[Dealer]
[number] [firstName] [surName]   [birthDate] [startWorkingDate] [ID]
Num Dealer|full name of Dealers| birthdate | date + time       | id number
[dbo].[Game]

[gameTypeName] [gameStartDateTime] [gameEndTime] [DealerInGame]
name of game  | date + time      | date + time| same numbers like [Dealer].[number]
```

What I want a query to do:
query that returns the dealer (employee number and full name), who participated in the smallest amount of games.

```
SELECT top 1 number,firstName +' '+ surName as 'full name' FROM Dealer
where  exists (SELECT gameTypeName,COUNT( gameTypeName)  FROM Game 
GROUP BY gameTypeName)
```

The query only brings me the first one that has the smallest amount of games, but if there are 2 or more dealers with the same value then it doesn't show them all.

What's wrong?

Comment: mysql or oracle ..?

Comment: dbo mean, SQL server?

Comment: Might want to mention what happens when you run your query.

Comment: Yeah, figure out which RDBMS you're using and amend the tags accordingly

Comment: EDIT the question

Answer (score 0):

I don't think, MySQL support the TOP operator as SQL Server does, but you can get the first record using LIMIT as below:

```
SELECT number,
       firstName +' '+ surName as 'full name'
FROM Dealer
where  exists (SELECT gameTypeName,COUNT( gameTypeName)
                 FROM Game 
        GROUP BY gameTypeName)
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: `LIMIT 1` without `ORDER BY` just selects a random row.

Comment: They said "who participated in the smallest amount of games".

Answer (score 0):

Join the two tables, use `COUNT()`, and then use `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT 1`. This is the MySQL syntax for it:

```
SELECT number, CONCAT(firstName, ' ', lastName) AS fullName
FROM Dealer AS d
JOIN Game AS g ON g.DealerInGame = d.number
GROUP BY d.number
ORDER BY COUNT(*)
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL? On SQL-Server you need to use `SELECT TOP 1`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the `join` :

```
select d.number, CONCAT(d.firstName, ' ', d.lastName) as fullName
from Dealer d inner join ( 
           select DealerInGame
           from Game
           group by DealerInGame
           having count(*) <= 1
      ) g on g.DealerInGame = d.number;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want all of the dealers with the smallest number of games, you will need to take the smallest number of games played and then find all the dealers with that number of games.

```
WITH GameCount as (
    SELECT 
        DealerInGame, 
        Count(*) Games
    FROM Game
    )

SELECT 
    d.firstName + ' ' + d.surName fullName,
    d.number
FROM GameCount g
    LEFT JOIN Dealer d on d.Number = g.DealerInGame
WHERE g.Games = (
    SELECT Min(Games)
    FROM GameCount)
```